# pylint "Undefined variable" in module written in C++/SIP

Tags: python, pylint

I export several native C++ classes to Python using SIP. I don't use the resulting `maplib_sip.pyd` module directly, but rather wrap it in a Python package`pymaplib`:

```
# pymaplib/__init__.py
# Make all of maplib_sip available in pymaplib.
from maplib_sip import *
...

def parse_coordinate(coord_str):
    ...
    # LatLon is a class imported from maplib_sip.
    return LatLon(lat_float, lon_float)
```

Pylint doesn't recognize that `LatLon` comes from `maplib_sip`:

```
error  pymaplib  parse_coordinate  40  15  Undefined variable 'LatLon'
```

Unfortunately, the same happens for all the classes from `maplib_sip`, as well as for most of the code from wxPython (Phoenix) that I use. This effectively makes Pylint worthless for me, as the amount of spurious errors dwarfs the real problems.

`additional-builtins` doesn't work that well for my problem:

```
# Both of these don't remove the error:
additional-builtins=maplib_sip.LatLon
additional-builtins=pymaplib.LatLon

# This does remove the error in pymaplib:
additional-builtins=LatLon

# But users of pymaplib still give an error:
#   Module 'pymaplib' has no 'LatLon' member
```

How do I deal with this? Can I somehow tell pylint that `maplib_sip.LatLon` actually exists? Even better, can it somehow figure that out itself via introspection (which works in IPython, for example)?

I'd rather not have to disable the undefined variable checks, since that's one of the huge benefits of pylint for me.

Program versions:
`Pylint 1.2.1`,
`astroid 1.1.1, common 0.61.0`,
`Python 3.3.3 [32 bit] on Windows7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to try the new `--ignored-modules` option, though I'm not sure it will work in your case, beside if you stop using `import *` (which would probably be a good idea as pylint probably already told you ;).

Rather use short import name, eg `import maplib_sip as mls`, then prefixed name, eg `mls.LatLon` where desired.

Notice though that the original problem is worth an issue on pylint tracker (https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issues) so some investigation will be done to grasp why it doesn't get member of your sip exported module.

Comment: It seems that pylint doesn't handle C++ extension modules (can't get an AST for it). Plus, it doesn't seem to have any options to tell it about (non-global-scope) classes that exist, but it can't know about. This seems like such a blatant omission that I'm baffled by it.